# How can we get value from DOM Properties in JMeter?

Tags: dom, jmeter

I'm trying to record a scenario of SAP CRM.
But I have a problem due to that everytime I login SAP CRM generates a new hashed token and will be used in URL like below:

[See Image 1 Here](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-gvA1cUjPY3c/VWWjBZdHi5I/AAAAAAAAMlQ/JqaiiSpINF0/s1600/image2.png)

I tried to check where is the information stored, and in firebug and I found it in DOM tab:

[See Image 2 Here](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-9MrYVawXoyI/VWWjweIrR9I/AAAAAAAAMlY/oomeEHcTVeI/s1600/image.png)

Is there any way to get the value from this DOM Properties using Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the choices are in:

- [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
- [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)
- [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

Choose the one, you're most familiar with. Usually it is Regular Expression Extractor, however [parsing HTML with regular expressions is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), moreover you will be very sensitive to DOM changes (part of the element goes to next line, attributes change positions, etc.).

So I would recommend choosing between CSS and XPath, but choose them wisely. I.e. if the number of styles on the page is not too big - go for CSS, if there are a lot of styles but the DOM itself is not very complicated - choose XPath.